# Upload base64 image to couchdb

Tags: python, flask, couchdb, httprequest, put

Im Trying to Upload a base64 image which I got from doing canvas.toDataUrl(); 
but nothing happens when I try and do a put request to couchdb. Im not sure how to retrieve the response to see if it worked.

**Here is my request:**

```
@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process():
email = request.form['email']
name = request.form['name'],
file = request.form['data'] #'data' is from html and was var srcdata = canvas.toDataURL()

if file:

     print(file)
     j = {"_id": "ab","_attachments":{"aboutme.jpg":{"content_type":"image/png","data":file}}}
     requests.put('http://127.0.0.1:5984/test2/',data=None,json=j)
```

**EDIT**

the string that is in the data value in the jj json works and allows me to upload and attachment to couchdb but when I pass it the file that doesnt work. Im thinking it doesnt because its not a proper base64, I think it could actually be a domString.

```
@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process():
email = request.form['email']
name = request.form['name'],
file = request.form['data']


if file:

     print(file)
     jj = {
         "_attachments":
             {
                 "aboutme.png":
                     {
                         "content_type": "image/png",
                         "data":"VGhpcyBpcyBhIGJhc2U2NCBlbmNvZGVkIHRleHQ="
                     }
             }
     }
     requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5984/test2/', data=None, json=jj)



return jsonify({'name': "yes"})
```

Comment: Your issue is with uploading bytearray-similar data using requests, not with Flask, correct?

Comment: yes. Im basically just trying to upload store and image to couchdb. I have base64 its just my code above is not working for me